# Session state is being reset when loading pages

Tags: php, session, oauth

I have an index.php page that sets a session state to let me know the user was there for when I authenticate using instagram and oauth.

```
session_start();
$state = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$_SESSION['state'] = $state;
$_SESSION['oauth_workflow'] = "front_page";
```

Now if I have another page, lets call it shop.php, and set a differnet workflow (of shop_page);

```
session_start();
$state = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$_SESSION['state'] = $state;
$_SESSION['oauth_workflow'] = "shop_page";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

When I access the shop.php page, the oauth workflow session variable says it is "shop page" as predicted. But if I have a thrid page called session.php and just dump the session out there,

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

I find that the session oauth workflow variable has been reset to "front_page", even though I never access the index.

I suspect that this has something to do with the .htaccess file but I cant pick the problem; The .htaccess file is there for URL aliases

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?q=$1 [L]
```

**How do I stop the index from resetting the oauth_workflow?**

EDIT:

callback.php (a simple switch statement)

```
// Figure out where we came from
session_start();
$oauth_workflow = $_SESSION['oauth_workflow'];


// figure out what action to take;
switch ($oauth_workflow) {

case 'font_page':
  //code
  break;
case 'shop_page':
  //code
  break;
}
```

Comment: The problem from first glance looks to be that the user is being sent to the front page, and then to the shop page? Are all your pages built off a single file?

Comment: @jjonesdesign No these are separate pages. My real issue is when the user returns from the instagram logon page, it must go to one callback page (as per instagram api). So from there I can use this oauth_workflow to redirect the user to the correct page. However its always returning with 'font_page'

Comment: Your question asks "How do I stop the index from resetting the oauth_workflow?" if the user is sent to a callback page, then they are never getting put back to the front page. To me, this either means the variable is getting reset on the callback page, or before being sent there. Can you dump the callback page for us?

Comment: You are exactly right and this is what I cannot understand. If I comment out the line `$_SESSION['oauth_workflow'] = "front_page";` in the index.php page it is fine and does not change the workflow. For this reason I believe the index is getting silently 'pinged' when any page loads.

Comment: @jjonesdesign added callback.php to show you how it works.

Comment: I am going to implement an ajax request/response to the index page to stop this from happening. I have tested it and it works. I am pretty sure I have an issue in the .htaccess code and every time I load any page it pings index.php before loading the correct page.